# Declaring two namespaces in the one file

Tags: php, namespaces, declaration, declare

As said in the `php reference`

> Namespaces are declared using the namespace keyword. A file containing
>   a namespace must declare the namespace at the top of the file before
>   any other code - with one exception: the declare keyword.

But further we've the following code snippet in the reference:

```
<?php
namespace MyProject;

const CONNECT_OK = 1;
class Connection { /* ... */ }
function connect() { /* ... */  }

namespace AnotherProject; //This namespace declaration doesn't located at the top of the file. It's unclear.

const CONNECT_OK = 1;
class Connection { /* ... */ }
function connect() { /* ... */  }
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One is declared at the top as first three lines under `MyProject` referes to `MyProject` namespace whereas other three under `AnotherProject` refers to `AnotherProject` namespace.
If at least one namespace is declared as the top, file will be correctly parsed (namespace will be switched dinamically)

Just to be more clear, you can even do that

```
<?php
namespace MyProject {

const CONNECT_OK = 1;
class Connection { /* ... */ }
function connect() { /* ... */  }
}

namespace AnotherProject {

const CONNECT_OK = 1;
class Connection { /* ... */ }
function connect() { /* ... */  }
}
?>
```

However is strongly not recommended to declare two namespaces inside same php script

Comment: It's obviously contradicts to `A file containing a namespace must declare the namespace at the top of the file before any other code`. Can you explain this?

Comment: @DmitryFucintv: why are you saying that? I can perfectly see namespace declaration at the top of the file, before all php code. As I told in my answer, at least one namespace should be declarated at the top, the others needs to be declared after (so not at the top) as all code under the declaration will refer to "new" namespace. Think about the scenario where you can declare three namespace at the top: at what namespace the code under should refers to?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But `at least one namespace should be declarated at the top` doesn't specified in the language reference. Why do you think so?

Comment: @DmitryFucintv empirical evidence. As deceze told into his answer, declare one namespace in the middle of a php file _without_ have one at the top result in a file that can't be parsed correctly

Comment: I'm understand you. So I'm assume that it's spec's lack.

Comment: @DmitryFucintv: if you want to see it as a "lack" ok, it could be. But I suppose that this sentence is referred to files with single namespace so is perfectly legal

Answer (score 1):

You can *switch* to another namespace later on in the file, but if you *are* using namespaces at all, you have to declare a namespace as the first thing in the file. I.e., this does *not* work:

```
<?php

echo 'foo';

namespace Bar;

echo 'bar';
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But this namespaces deslared in the same file. AnotherProject namespace doesn't located at the top of this file. It's obviously contradicts to `A file containing a namespace must declare the namespace at the top of the file before any other code`

Comment: It does not. If the file uses a namespace at all, it must be declared at the top of the file. It does not say that no further namespace declaration may follow.

Comment: `If the file uses a namespace at all, it must be declared at the top of the file. It does not say that no further namespace declaration may follow.` It doesn't specified in the spec.

Comment: It is also not *not* specified in the documentation. What is written in the documentation is literally true and correct. One part says that you have to write namespace declarations at the top of the file if any are used, another part says that you can write further namespace declarations below.