# End syntax for unbracketed namespace (to mix with bracketed namespace)

Tags: php, namespaces

As we know, we can't use/mix namespaces in a single file like this:

```
namespace A;
...
...
namespace B{
   ...
}
```

does there exist any `end` syntax for unbracketed namespace, so it would become available to mix two namespaces?  (like it's `endif;` for unbracketed `if`) ?

p.s. please, don't suggest to use brackets, I know that already (hence, my question is not "how to mix two namespaces in single file").  but my question is what I ask - if there is an `end` syntax for unbracketed NS.

Comment: I would like to emphasise the comment in the answer **However is strongly not recommended to declare two namespaces inside same php script**

Comment: No, it's not possible. Hence the fatal error *Cannot mix bracketed namespace declarations with unbracketed namespace declarations...*

Comment: @NigelRen are you sure that this is a duplicate question? please, re-read it  -it is different.

Comment: I flagged the dupe as that is how is has to be done AFAIK.  If you want me to remove it and see if anyone can come up with something else then I will.  It would probably help if you added a specific use case so that it would explain why you want to do this to make the context clearer (IMHO).

Comment: The dupe I flagged was https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22606792/declaring-two-namespaces-in-the-one-file, but see if anything else comes up.

Comment: I think the main problem is a case of which namespace should it use at any point when two namespaces are in play.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no alternative syntax and `endnamespace` keyword, because there is no real need for it.

Using multiple namespaces in one file is a bad practice and should be avoided anyway, so one way to do this is more than enough. `if` and `endif` (and similar) was designed for using in templates since it increase readability when you mix HTML and PHP code. But views does not need to use namespaces at all, thus there is no pointless `endnamespace` tag. Using brackets is the only way to mix two namespaces in one file*.

<sub>* I don't count some ugly hacks like using `eval()`.</sub>

Comment: I don't agree with `there is no real need for it`. If there exists `{}` for namespaces, to define its start and end, then that means there is a need to end the namespace. and if the namespaces can be declared with two different methods, both of them should have the endings.

Comment: @T.Todua You have two ways of declaring namespace: file-level (declares namespace for the whole file content) and custom-scope-level (declares namespace for content inside of `{}` brackets). You don't need custom tag to end file-level namespace, because end of file is natural end for this scope.